# how to add a component .Net (video conference by XSocket.Net ) in a page of wordpress?

Tags: c#, wordpress, webrtc, integrate, xsockets.net

I would  integrate my application of chat video developed using  `xsocket.net`  in **Wordpress**.

How to do this integration ?

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a problem, but maybe I do not understand your question?

Since the integration is JavaScript only you should be able to just move the JavaScript to you wordpress solution. Then connect to the XSockets server as usual.